# Constraints in Xcode 8

Tags: ios, autolayout, constraints, xcode8, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to pin all labels and buttons using auto layout. But it seems to be impossible. I've tried almost everything (tutorials also - been there done that), and it still sucks. On every device (Iphone 7plus, 6) it looks much different, sometimes labels hide, or disappear. 
Please, help.

my labels:

- log in/sign up
- email address
- password
- skip

text field:

- 2, under email address and password

background:

- image view

[image]

Comment: do you have constraints to the super view or other views ?

Comment: I tried both, and didnt work... Probably mixed them : (

Comment: upload a screen shot of your constraints

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a storyboard with one view controller in it.
it contains what should be the correct constraints.

try using that view.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3ALyHCgvMCQMm1CQWJDdEw2S3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I've tried used it in my storyboard, but after one day struggling, I have no idea how to do it in my file. Could You look at this? Here is my storyboard and I set for  iphone 7.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B68OpxRinURkR2lLSFhXRmZZWms/view?usp=sharing

and here my UI APP: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B68OpxRinURkS3gwYlN6N1BxeU0/view?usp=sharing

Comment: did you tried to copy and paste the view controller onto your storyboard?